# IFrame pointed to localhost in the Dashboard

Tags: localhost, dynamics-crm

I've tried different ways to embed a local url for testing purposes. It's too slow to update something, go through the upload/publish process and test.

After following [this](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/embed-website-dynamics-crm-dashboard/) link for the standard implementation, I've tried linking as:

> http://localhost/path-to-folder/index.html
>
> http://127.0.0.1/path-to-folder/index.html

I've created a virtual host as well:

> http://myusername.local/path-to-folder/index.html

All of the urls are accessible on my test machine and it's just that dynamics is not letting it go and at the end after publishing I see a blank white page, although within CRM and under developer tools I can confirm that the URL was correctly referenced as below.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="IFRAME_admin" name="IFRAME_admin" class="ms-crm-Custom" 
    delayinitialize="0" tabindex="0" 
    url="http://myusername.local:80/path-to-folder/index.html" scrolling="auto" preload="0" 
    src="http://myusername.local:80/path-to-folder/index.html">
</iframe>
```

Any suggestions?

As a last resort, I'm thinking to register a domain name and override the name in my virtual hosts to point to local address, not sure if this will work. I'm testing this on the Mac if that makes any difference.

I'm testing on production CRM, should I move to sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You need a short turnaround for dev & deploy process for Dynamics CRM webresources, that too a very rare Mac + MS development + non-Visual studio combo.

I would recommend [Dynamics Dev Helpmate](https://devhelpmate.osmosys.asia), which is a bookmark for browser. I use this in chrome, which enables editing js webresource from current form in few clicks.